# Where are the drawables or clipart from android.R.drawable stored?

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, actionbarsherlock

I am integrating ActionBarSherlock in my app and I want to have some menus with some items and its respective icons.

I have looked into samples and documentation, and everything seems to be clear, but when I Inflate the menu, I can see just the text because there are no icons related to each item yet.

I would like to use the icons you see when creating an android project:

[image: Android New Project Clipart]

But I can't find it, and I don't want to use direct reference to android.R.drawable in order to use those clipart icons, because I have read it is recommended to have the files in drawable folders.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
android-sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res/drawable-yyyy
```

where xx is your target platform and yyyy is mdpi, hdpi, etc.

Copy the icons you want into the appropriate resource folder in your project.

Comment: Exactly the folder I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: But isn't that supposed to be available by default without having to copy them? If it is part of the sdk, why do we have to copy them to our project folders?

Comment: @James Memory is a major limitation for mobile applications. if every app had every icon in every size, even though you only need a handful of them, you'd just be wasting space. You pick and choose what you need for your app, just like you don't leave the house with six full changes of clothing just to go out to lunch.

Comment: @MarsAtomic True but there should be a way in Android Studio to select the one you want for the app and then it should do the copying.

Answer (score 8):

I generally use [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html) to create icons for my apps. It has all the standard clipart, and can generate the proper files for all other icons as well.

Answer (score 6):

http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html site has Action Bar Icon Pack

Comment: It doesn't seem to be there anymore. The only relevant-looking link was for the Material Icons (which is a 404). The Material Icons are now here: https://material.io/icons/ I think some of them might be built into android, but you can also download them if you want to. They are advertised to specifically to be used in android applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can use system icons by using "@android:" prefix. The icon is not copied to drawable folders, so the application size is smaller"

Example:  `android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"`

List of icons at /platforms/android-/data/res/drawable-hdpi

Note 1: If you want to copy the icons to drawable files you can also do it in eclipse by using file /new/other/Anddoid icon set/clipart button/choose button.

Note 2: the icon set could change among platforms. That is why people are suggesting to copy resources. If the applicacion is just at development state you could just link the platform icons